# How to upload file using PHP and HTML in Ionic?

Tags: php, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to use this HTML and PHP code in Ionic to upload an image. How to use this code in Ionic?

**HTML**

```
<form action="http://sco7.com/del/uploadtest/uploadionic.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);

    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You can use File Transfer

Answer (score 0):

Why use PHP code inside an IONIC app?
Use http POST method to upload files via APIs
Below is a simple example
Install the plugin in your app

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/http
```

Import it in your app

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';
```

Initialize it in the constructor

```
constructor(public http: HTTP){}
```

Now you can make a POST request

```
this.http.psot("your/api/endpoint", {"fileName":"filedata"}, {"Authorization":"some auth"})
.then(()=>{ console.log('file uploaded')});
```

You may want to convert the file data into Base64 or a Blob